# React Native: Does Reanimated2 work on the web in a managed Expo project?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

As per the documentation provided [here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/reanimated/), it looks like ReAnimated2 should work in a managed Expo project but we just won't get remote js debugging.

> The new APIs in react-native-reanimated@2 use React Native APIs that are incompatible with Remote JS Debugging.

And then as per the `ReAnimated` docs [here](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/web-support), from my understanding, it looks like it only works with a self-managed or ejected workflow, and NOT using managed Expo.

Furthermore, the animations in this example Expo Snack don't work on the web.

1. Can someone confirm that `ReAnimated2` doesn't work on a managed Expo project?
2. Was the default Animated API from react-native developed after and in response to `ReAnimated2`?
3. Since the default Animated API from React-Native allows you to `useNativeDriver` anyways, pretty much everything can be achieved using the native API right - albeit with more code?

[Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@paulwongx/rnreanimatednotworkingonweb)